# How to change the image within a UIImageView inside an iOS app?

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage

I have a UIImageView object that I instantiate and turn into a property inside my iOS app.  I initialize the attributes for this UIImageView object inside my viewDidLoad method, however, I need to change the image that is contained inside the UIImageView object later on in another method.  When I do this, I for some reason am simply superimposing the new image over top of the old one.  What I would like to do is simply resize the frame, and replace the old image with the new one.

Here is the relevant code:

Inside my viewDidLoad method:

```
imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 250, 300, 200)];
imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"firstImage.png"];
[self.view addSubview:imageView];
```

and inside my method where I wish to make the changes:

```
imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 250, 200, 300)];
imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"secondImage.png"];
[self.view addSubview:imageView];
```

Please bear in mind that I don't want to just change the image, but also the frame size to accommodate the new image.  Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating another instance of imageview. You need to access the same object and change frame and image there.

Try this,

Create `imageView` as property in the class as,

In .h file,

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *imageView;
```

Then in `viewDidLoad`,

```
self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 250, 300, 200)];
self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"firstImage.png"];
[self.view addSubview:imageView];
```

The in second method, just change the frame and image as shown below,

```
self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(10, 250, 200, 300);
self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"secondImage.png"];
```

As per you code, you were creating separate instances for imageViews and adding as subviews which will cause it to superimpose on another one. Instead you need to create a single instance as shown above and modify its frame and image properties whenever required.